# `-bash: rbenv: command not found` comes up every time I open a terminal window. How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, homebrew, rbenv

I tried installing rails using rbenv, but was unsuccessful.  I then uninstalled rbenv and installed rails with rvm.  Now every time I open my terminal window I get the follow

```
 Last login: Wed Jul 17 21:59:43 on ttys001
 -bash: rbenv: command not found
 -bash: rbenv: command not found
 name-Mac-mini:~ name$
```

When I use homebrew to uninstall I get

```
$ brew uninstall rbenv
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv
```

I have mac-mini running Mountain Lion 10.8.4.  Any ideas on how I can get fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to see your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files, I would guess that you have a line in one of them what is supposed to be loading something from rbenv.

I would check there to see if there is something that might be loading is.

Comment: thanks, I found some rbenv references and commented them out. Terminal now loads fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem and here was my fix. Like [zchrykng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2276578/zchrykng) said, it was a line in my `.bash_profile`.

Run
`$ sudo pico .bash_profile` to open up the file for edit. (You will have to enter your password)

I had to remove `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` which was at the bottom of the document repeated twice. After removing these lines, save and you shouldn't see the error anymore.